# What online retailers sell vintage games or box art?

Tags: backwards-compatibility

I've been looking for an original Archon I for C64 for ages now, but all the offers on ebay are crazy expensive. So I thought I'd ask if anybody knows an online retailer that does trading of very old vintage video games?

I'm not interested in ROMs, as in fact I want the game just for the beautiful packaging it came with.

Comment: I'd hate to rain on your parade, but people sell those things for outrageous prices because they are extremely rare, which is why I doubt there's an established dealer out there who would sell it for cheap. Since you state you want it mainly as a showpiece, it might prove easier/cheaper to construct a fake box, assuming the box's art is easier to come by.

Comment: @Aubergine you might want to turn that comment into an answer, as it is the correct answer.

Comment: @alexanderpas: Thanks for the vote of confidence, but the reason it wasn't an answer to begin with is that I'm not 100% sure that there's no reasonably priced copy to be found anywhere. Of course, assuming Sorcy says he'll accept this, I will gladly make an answer of my comment.

Comment: Since there is no better answer I would totally accept this.

Comment: This is off-topic, as per our [FAQ]. Specifically, "Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game) and Shopping advice and recommendations"

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Wipqozn's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old games that are in excellent condition can potentially be worth a lot of money, so it is not surprising that you have found **Archon I** sell for a lot of money on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com).  If you are adamant about obtaining this game, you need to research how much the game has been selling for over the last year or two and be prepared to pay approximately the same amount for the game.  It will require patience and self restraint, but you should eventually be able to purchase that game you so desire.

[Racketboy.com](http://www.racketboy.com) is my favorite community driven retro games website out there.  They have some great guides to help you get informed on the best way to proceed with retro game purchases:

- [How To Find The Best Gaming Deals on eBay](http://www.racketboy.com/retro/game-collecting/2008/06/how-to-find-the-best-gaming-deals-on-ebay.html)
- [Comparing Massive Markups For Pristine Retro Games](http://www.racketboy.com/retro/game-collecting/2008/04/comparing-values-of-sealed-and-complete-video-games.html)
- [Learn How Much Your Video Games Are Worth](http://www.racketboy.com/retro/game-collecting/2010/02/learn-how-much-video-games-are-worth.html)

They also have a thriving forum with several members that are avid retro gamers and game collectors (some of them even own video game stores), and many of them have channels that they can call upon to find rare games for a fair price.

Comment: I've watched ebay for the game for several months now, and the really frustrating thing is, that it is put out there for a big price and, as far as the ones I watched go, NEVER EVER has been sold for this price. But apparently that's okay, because a few weeks later it goes right up there again, with the same price.